# How to specialize base class template method from derived class?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, template-specialization

I'm trying to specialize a base class method from a derived class template, but I'm not sure what would be the proper syntax to achieve it.

For implementation reasons, I need a class structure similar to the one below, but need to specialize `func()` from the top-level class:

```
template < typename T >
class BaseTemplate {
 public:
    BaseTemplate() = default;
    virtual ~BaseTemplate() = default;

    virtual void func() {
        std::cout << __func__ << std::endl;
    }
};



class DerivedBase : public BaseTemplate< float > {
 public:
    DerivedBase() : BaseTemplate() { /* ... */}
    virtual ~DerivedBase() = default;
};



template < typename U >
class DerivedTemplate : public DerivedBase {
 public:
    DerivedTemplate() : DerivedBase() { /* ... */ }
    ~DerivedTemplate() = default;

 protected:
    U _member;
};


template < >
void DerivedTemplate< int >::func() {
    std::cout << __func__ << " [int]" << std::endl;  // error: no member function ‘func’ declared in ‘DerivedTemplate<int>’
}
```

Additionaly, explicitly declaring `using DerivedBase::func;` in `DerivedTemplate` results in another error:

```
error: template-id ‘func<>’ for ‘void DerivedTemplate<int>::func()’ does not match any template declaration
```

Comment: You have not declared the overriding `func` in `DerivedTemplate`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to specialize base class function in your case. Since function `func()` is virtual you can just implement it in one of your derived classes (either in `DerivedTemplate` or `DerivedBase` or both if needed):

```
template < typename U >
class DerivedTemplate : public DerivedBase {
 public:
    DerivedTemplate() : DerivedBase() { /* ... */ }
    ~DerivedTemplate() = default;

    virtual void func() override {
        std::cout << __func__ << "(DerivedTemplate version)" << std::endl;
    }
 protected:
    U _member;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

> Additionaly, explicitly declaring using DerivedBase::func; in
> DerivedTemplate results in another error:
> error: template-id ‘func<>’ for ‘void DerivedTemplate::func()’
> does not match any template declaration

`DerivedBase::func;` method is defined but not declared. You need to add `void func();` in `DerivedTemplate`.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/PaEnMxEn8)

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // cout

template <typename T>
class BaseTemplate {
public:
    BaseTemplate() = default;
    virtual ~BaseTemplate() = default;

    virtual void func() {
        std::cout << __func__ << " [BaseTemplate]\n";
    }
};

class DerivedBase : public BaseTemplate<float> {
public:
    DerivedBase() : BaseTemplate<float>{} {}
    virtual ~DerivedBase() = default;
};

template <typename U>
class DerivedTemplate : public DerivedBase {
public:
    DerivedTemplate() : DerivedBase{} {}
    ~DerivedTemplate() = default;

    void func();
};

template <>
void DerivedTemplate<int>::func() {
    std::cout << __func__ << " [DerivedTemplate<int>]\n";
}

int main() {
    BaseTemplate<char> bt{}; bt.func();
    DerivedTemplate<int> dti{}; dti.func();
}

// Outputs:
//
//   func [BaseTemplate]
//   func [DerivedTemplate<int>]
```

What you could do in your example is to access `BaseTemplate::func` from `DerivedTemplate<int>`.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/x7jxcqfPj)

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // cout

template <typename T>
class BaseTemplate {
public:
    BaseTemplate() = default;
    virtual ~BaseTemplate() = default;

    virtual void func() {
        std::cout << __func__ << " [BaseTemplate]";
    }
};

class DerivedBase : public BaseTemplate<float> {
public:
    DerivedBase() : BaseTemplate<float>{} {}
    virtual ~DerivedBase() = default;
};

template <typename U>
class DerivedTemplate : public DerivedBase {
public:
    DerivedTemplate() : DerivedBase{} {}
    ~DerivedTemplate() = default;

    void func();
};

template <>
void DerivedTemplate<int>::func() {
    BaseTemplate::func();
    std::cout << " [int]";
}

int main() {
    DerivedTemplate<int> dti{}; dti.func();
}

// Outputs:
//
//   func [BaseTemplate] [int]
```

Also, if you plan to use runtime polymorphism with this hierarchy, you'll want to use `virtual void func() override` in some of your classes.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/Yfnz3djfP)

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <memory>  // make_unique, unique_ptr

template <typename T>
class BaseTemplate {
public:
    BaseTemplate() = default;
    virtual ~BaseTemplate() = default;

    virtual void func() {
        std::cout << __func__ << " [BaseTemplate]\n";
    }
};

class DerivedBase : public BaseTemplate<float> {
public:
    DerivedBase() : BaseTemplate<float>{} {}
    virtual ~DerivedBase() = default;

    virtual void func() override {
        std::cout << __func__ << " [DerivedBase]\n";
    }
};

template <typename U>
class DerivedTemplate : public DerivedBase {
public:
    DerivedTemplate() : DerivedBase{} {}
    ~DerivedTemplate() = default;

    virtual void func() override {
        std::cout << __func__ << " [DerivedTemplate]\n";
    }
};

template <>
void DerivedTemplate<int>::func() {
    std::cout << __func__ << " [DerivedTemplate<int>]\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<BaseTemplate<float>> dti_up{std::make_unique<DerivedTemplate<int>>()};
    dti_up->func();
}

// Outputs:
//
//  func [DerivedTemplate<int>]
```

Comment: This doesn't require an override in `DerivedBase`.

Comment: @aschepler You are right. I was maybe thinking in this case: https://godbolt.org/z/PGG18sPPY. I'll update. Thanks!

Comment: But why is there a need for explicit overriding the base virtual method? Why doesn't an `using BaseTemplate<>::func;` suffice on the top-level class? My base implementation would be enough for most types `U`, but occasionally I would like to specialize it. Having to explicit override a base method to forward eventual arguments to its base implementation seems a bit convoluted.

Comment: That's basically what happens in the first example above (except that you don't need the `using`). Have a look at this variation of that first example: `BaseTemplate`, `DerivedBase` and `DerivedTemplate` objects all use `BaseTemplate::func`; `DerivedTemplate<int>` objects use `DerivedTemplate<int>::func`: https://godbolt.org/z/Gx59vqjEq